# Does it follow that for $ x\ge 785, (2x+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln x}} < 4$

Tags: derivatives, inequality, logarithms, exponential-function, solution-verification

Does it follow that for $ x\ge 785$,

$$(2x+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln x}} < 4$$

Note:  $1.25506$ is taken from this [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities) regarding the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(x)$:

Here's my thinking:

(1) $(2(785+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln 785}} < 4$

To complete the argument, I need to show that for $x \ge 785$, $(2x+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln x}}$ is decreasing.

(2)  $(2x+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln x}}$ is decreasing if and only if $\dfrac{1.25506}{\ln x}\ln (2x+3)$ is decreasing so let:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{1.25506}{\ln x}\ln (2x+3)$$

(3)  Using the [Quotient Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_rule) with $g(x) = 1.25506\ln (2x+3)$ and $h(x) = \ln x$:

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2}$$

(4)  Using the [Product Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule) with $s(x) = 1.25506$ and $t(x)=\ln(2x+3)$

$$g'(x) = s'(x)t(x) + s(x)t'(x)$$

(5)  Using the [Chain Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) for $t(x)$ with $q(x) = 2x+3$ and $p(x) = \ln(q(x))$:

$$t'(x) = p'(q(x))'q(x) = (\ln(2x+3))'(2x+3)' = \frac{2}{2x+3}$$

(6)  Applying Step(5):

$$g'(x) = 1.25506\frac{2}{2x+3} = \frac{2.51012}{2x+3}$$

(7)  Applying Step(4):

$$f'(x) = \frac{g'(x)h(x) - g(x)h'(x)}{[h(x)]^2} = \frac{\frac{2.51012\ln x}{2x+3} - \frac{1.25506\ln (2x+3)}{x}}{(\ln x)^2}$$

(8) The derivative is negative when:

$$\frac{1.25506\ln (2x+3)}{x} > \frac{2.51012\ln x}{2x+3}$$

Restated as:

$$(2x+3)\ln (2x+3) > 2x\ln x$$

which is true for $x > 0$

Is this argument valid?  Did I ma 1.25506\ln (2x+3)ke a mistake or present an incomplete argument?  In my reasoning in Step(9) sufficient?

---

**Edit:**  I have restated the question with help from the commenters

Even though I have accepted an answer, please post comments if you see any mistakes or have suggestions for improvements.

Comment: If you want to show that $F(x)=(2x+3)^{\frac{1.25506}{\ln x}}$ is decreasing, why are you considering the derivative of $\frac x{F(x)}$?

Comment: It certainly looks wrong to me.

Comment: I believe that I messed.  I was trying to show that $x$ gets larger as a ratio.

Comment: Thanks.  I will fix it.  I think that I got a head of myself.  :-(

Comment: It would be easier to show that $\ln (f(x)) = c\frac{\ln (2x+3)}{\ln x}$ is decreasing using the quotient rule to show that the derivative is negative.

Comment: Thanks, @Anand.  I will attempt that when I rework my question.  The approach I was taking seemed to be more difficult than I had expected.

Comment: I think that short table I put at the end of my answer explains a lot of problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just penciling out the ideas in the comments. Let $f(x)$ be your function:
$$
f'(x) = \frac{(2 x+3)^{1.25506/\log(x)}}{\log(x)^2}\left(\frac{2.51012\log(x)}{2x+3} - \frac{1.25506 \log(2x+3)}{x}\right)
$$Tedious arithmetic shows the second term in parentheses has no real solution and $f'(1)\approx -2.02$. Then $f'$ is always negative, and another calculation shows $f(785)\approx 3.99854$. So yes, eventually $f(x)<4$.

Answer (score 2):

Solution without derivatives.

We need to prove that $$(2x+3)^{1.25506}<4^{\ln{x}}$$ or
$$e^{\ln4\ln{x}}-(2x+3)^{1.25506}>0$$ or
$$x^{\ln4}-(2x+3)^{1.25506}>0$$ or
$$x^{\ln4-1.25506}-\left(2+\frac{3}{x}\right)^{1.25506}>0,$$ which is true because
$$x^{\ln4-1.25506}-\left(2+\frac{3}{x}\right)^{1.25506}\geq785^{\ln4-1.25506}-\left(2+\frac{3}{785}\right)^{1.25506}\approx0.0058>0.$$
Now we see  that our inequality is true even for any $x\geq771.$

Answer (score 2):

Making the problem a bit more general, I should consider that we need to find the zero of function
$$f(x)=\frac{a }{\log (x)}\log (2 x+3)-\log (b)$$
Expanded as a Taylor series, we have
$$f(x)=\left(\frac{a \log (2)}{\log (x)}+a-\log (b)\right)+\frac{3 a}{2 x \log
   (x)}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ the solution of which being given in terms of Lambert function
$$x=-\frac{3 a}{2 (a-\log (b))} \frac 1{ W\left(-\frac{a}{a-\log (b)} k^{-\frac{a}{a-\log (b)}}\right)}\qquad \text{where} \qquad k=\frac 13 \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{\frac{\log (b)}{a}}$$

Using your constant this gives as an estimate $x_0=770.873$. Using Newton method, the iterates for $f(x)=0$ would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 770.8726304 \\
 1 & 770.8589458 \\
 2 & 770.8589459
\end{array}
\right)$$

**Edit**

If we use only the first term of the expansion
$$\frac{a \log (2)}{\log (x)}+a-\log (b)=0 \implies x=2^{-\frac{a}{a-\log (b)}}$$ which, using your numbers, gives as a simple estimate $x=756.6600$ which is not bad.

It is also interesting to notice the very strong dependency of $x$ to $b$. Using the original equation, be have that
$$\frac{db}{dx}=\frac{a \left(\frac{2}{2 x+3}-\frac{\log (2 x+3)}{x \log (x)}\right) (2x+3)^{\frac{a}{\log (x)}}}{\log (x)}$$ which around $x=771$ gives $$\frac{db}{dx}\approx -1.04\times 10^{-4}$$

This probably explains why we need quite accurate calculations.

To illustrate the need of rather accurate calculations
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & b \\
 760 & 4.00114 \\
 765 & 4.00061 \\
 770 & 4.00009 \\
 775 & 3.99957 \\
 780 & 3.99905 \\
 785 & 3.99854 \\
 790 & 3.99804 \\
 795 & 3.99753 \\
 800 & 3.99703
\end{array}
\right)$$